# How to remove extra space between sectioning and text in TEX

Tags: sectioning, white-space, vspace

I'm currently writing my final project report, 
while inputting all chapters in one main file
only the second chapter adds some extra spacing between the section, subsection... and the text and figures, the 1st and 3rd chapters are fine.

**I tried everything like:**

```
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt} % this reduces space between (sub)sections to 0pt, for example
\AtBeginDocument{%                  
% this will reduce spaces between parts (above and below) of texts within a (sub)section to 0pt, for example - like between an 'eqnarray' and text  
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}  
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}}
```

**and I tried:**

```
\vspace{-2cm}
```

But nothing worked, :( so please help me on how I can fix this problem.
Here is a picture of the 1st chapter and the 2nd one, which has been driving me crazy for the last three days:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I reformatted the code to look more like it would appear in a .tex file.  To do this, highlight the code block, and click on the `{}` icon above the question box.

Comment: Add `\raggedbottom` to your document preamble. I'm quite sure you have another `\subsubsection` with a picture on the next page.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thank you, it seems i still have a lot to learn ^^

Comment: @egreg: I'm so grateful, it worked perfectly, I'm so glad that i came here, thank you so much now i can finish my report :)